# What is a clabject?

Tags: oop, object, modeling, metamodel

I am trying to find a clear definition of clabject.

Has anyone a good one ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paper on [The Rationale of Powertype-based Metamodelling to Underpin Software Development Methodologies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.59.2562&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives a definition of clabjets, two faceted constructs that have properties of classes and objects:

> This idea of a two-faceted construct
>   or clabject is perfect for our needs,
>   since it nicely models a single
>   concept being modelled simultaneously
>   as a class and as an object. Rather
>   than seeing the WriteMethodCode class
>   and the “WriteMethodCode” object as
>   separate entities in the method layer,
>   we can look at them as a single
>   entity, a clabject, named
>   #WriteMethodCode. As such, #WriteMethodCode will exhibit a class facet (with a name and possibly some
>   attributes and relationships) plus an
>   object facet (with values and links).
>   The class facet of a method-level
>   clabject, as we have explained before,
>   is a subtype of a metamodel class
>   (Task in our example), while the
>   object facet in the same clabject is
>   an instance of a different metamodel
>   class.

Comment: The concept wasn't invented there. It was introduced, as far as I know, by Atkinson & Kühne in some of their papers from the early 2000s, and then used by us in a number of papers that Boris quotes in the metamodelling area. It is also used and defined semi-formally by the ISO/IEC 24744 standard. But, basically, the definition given by Boris is correct.